# How to connect a users table with a friends table?

Tags: mysql, database

I am doing a database on phpmyadmin. One of my tasks is to do a table called Users. One of the features the users will have is the ability to add another user as a friend. However, I am not sure how to go about this..

I thought of creating another table with the same data and use that ID as FK, however thought it was a bad idea since it is a many-to-many relationship.Instead, do I use the same table and do a foreign Key (Friend_id) inside it and give it an index and do a constraint using the same table?

Comment: I assume you are asking about database, not how to use this tool. You should tag it with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you ever going to give me up?

Comment: im not gonna let you down either!